# Unable to find pattern in coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have found the following first part of a series:

$$1+x+x^2+\frac{4}{3}x^3+\frac{7}{6}x^4+\frac{6}{5}x^5+\frac{37}{30}x^6+\frac{404}{315}x^7+...$$

However, I just cant seem to find the pattern in the coefficients. Is any of you able to? Like, you could rewrite the denominators to $k!$, but then the numerators don't make sense.

__

Comment: Where did the series come from?

Comment: We had to use Picard iteration to solve dy/dx=x^2+y^2, y(0)=1

Comment: WolframAlpha gives the solution to this equation ODE in terms of a nasty combination of Bessel functions. I imagine you would have to use some heavy computer algebra software to get series coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering why they would make us solve this by hand??

Comment: if you look more carefully at the problem and associated reading, something should appear.

Comment: Are you sure they don’t want just the first few terms?

Comment: I guess the other option is to plug a power series into the equation and equate coefficients, but for a nonlinear equation like this I doubt that will be fruitful

Answer (score 1):

The first 8-term Maclaurin series  of

$$y(x) = \frac{x^2 J_{5/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{3}{4} \right) - x^2 J_{1/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{1}{4} \right) + J_{1/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{3}{4} \right)  - x^2 J_{3/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{3}{4} \right) }{x\, J_{1/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{1}{4} \right) -2\,J_{-1/4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(
 \frac{3}{4} \right) }$$

is the term you have posted in your question. In this context $J_{v}(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and  $\Gamma \left(x \right)$ is the gamma function ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)).

Comment: The asker may have wanted to find a pattern for the coefficients rather than a closed form for $y(x)$.

Comment: From this function the OP can find the pattern, right? The other way round is impossible.

Comment: @callculus42: How did you find $y(x)$?

Comment: @Moo I just used Google :-)

Comment: Good thinking! :-) - I usually do that for most things.